# How to use bundleFileName of maven-ear-plugin in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, intellij-idea

I have a maven ear module with the following configuration for my ear file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <displayName>app</displayName>
        <description>app</description>
        <modules>
            ...
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>example-client</artifactId>
               <bundleFileName>example-client.jar</bundleFileName>
            </ejbModule>
            ..
        </modules>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <version>5</version>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I use Intellij (ultimate 12.1.4) to deploy my ear to a jboss as, the bundleFileName is ignored.

It creates a jar file with version number, but in the application.xml the jar file is defined without version.

Is there a way to fix this? I deploy using the "exploded" ear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed in Intelij 13 (currently not yet release): see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114355